# Replace Bootstrap modal's body by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to replace Bootstrap modal's body by clicking on link. Here is my code:

**index.php:**

```
<div id="regModal" class = "modal fade" role = "dialog">
    <div class ="modal-content">
        <div class ="modal-header">...</div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 login-modal">...</div>
                <div  class="col-xs-12 register-modal hidden">...<div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class ="modal-footer"><a>click</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**style.css:**

```
#regModal .hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

**modal.js:**

```
$("#regModal a").click(function(evt) {
    $("#regModal .login-modal").fadeOut();
    $("#regModal .hidden").fadeIn();        
});
```

It's actually hide whole of modal. how to replace *login-modal* with *register-modal*?

Comment: Does your *actual* link have  something like `href="#regModal" data-toggle="modal"` on it by chance?  I ask because your js code works fine, see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/3n2qfmaL/)

Comment: @DelightedD0D, I don't see the register-modal "fading in" in the fiddle

Comment: Sorry, your statement *It's actually hide whole of **modal**. how to replace login-modal with register-modal?* was misleading due to poorly named selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use the class `.hidden` in your DOM manipulation. Bootstrap uses this class a lot and it's css uses `display:none !important` and it seems to be mucking up your selectors

**Note** that I have also changed your classes to `login-div` and `register-div` because to me, `login-modal` doesnt convey what the element actually is, I would expect that to be an actual modal

[See this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/3n2qfmaL/)

```js
$("#regModal").modal('show');
$("#regModal a").click(function(evt) {
  $("#regModal .login-div").fadeOut();
  $("#regModal .register-div").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
#regModal .register-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="regModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">modal-header</div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 login-div">login-div</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 register-div "><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><a>click</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can able to see some tweaks on your existing code.

1) `<div>` not properly closed on `.register-modal`.

2) By default `.hidden` class have `display:none !important` property on bootstrap.

now fix the above tweaks. your code will working properly.

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcstqq9u/1/)

```js
$("#regModal a").click(function(evt) {
    $("#regModal .login-modal").fadeOut();
    $("#regModal .register-modal").fadeIn(200);
});
```

```css
.register-modal{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" href="modal.html" id="btn_port" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#regModal">Modal!</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="regModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">           
                <div class="login-modal">Login</div>
                <div  class="register-modal">register</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <a>click</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```